# Turning a vector of length n squared into a matrix of size n times n python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vector, reshape

In python I have a numpy vector array v of length n squared. I want to make it into a matrix M of size n times n, by laying the elements of n into n rows, so the first n elements of v comprise the first row of M, similarly the i-th n elements of v comprise the i-th row of M.

I tired using numpy reshape, but as I am completely new to python I couldn't figure out how this is done. How can the above be done?

Comment: you haven't posted any code. please post the code of what you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're definitely on the right track, you want to use [`np.reshape()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) here by doing

```
M = M.reshape(n,n)
```

or

```
M = np.reshape(M, (n,n))
```

Note the extra parentheses in the second case, they are important for it to work right because you are passing the tuple (n,n) as an argument.